# scala spark read csv corrupted/Double Spaced text? How to fix?

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark

When reading csv files pushed to an S3 bucket, the headers are not read properly and there is a space between each character. The only current solution I have is to manually download the file from the bucket, save it in excel, and re upload to S3. Here is what the corrupt file looks like
[notice the spaces between characters.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sfk5t.png)

How would I go about fixing this? Thanks

Comment: Is the issue only with the columns right?

Comment: no, all of the text, columns, rows and cells, show up with a blank space between them. it is some encoding error